# ERROR : A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to get record type id's from sub query under map, when I am iterating over map values I am getting **"A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression"** error

My requirement is to throw error if more than one record created per record type, so trying to capture Record type id and account Id.

```
public static void throwerror(list<sObject> dataset){
        List<Plan__c > Plans = (List<Plan__c >)dataset;
        Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Plan__c ap:plans){
            if(ap.Account__c != null)
            accIds.add(ap.Account__c); 
        }
        Map<Id, Account> accMap = new  Map<Id, Account>([Select id , (Select Id,RecordType.Name,RecordTypeId From Plan__r) From Account Where Id IN :accIds ]);
        map<Id,String> keymap = new map<Id,String>();
         for(Account acc : accMap.values()){
             keymap.put(acc.Id,acc.Plan__r.RecordTypeId);// Error : A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: Plan__r
         }
         system.debug('--->>>'+keymap);
         for(Plan__c ap:plans){
                        //here I want to include condition to check if accid and plan record id exists
            if(accMap.containsKey(ap.Account__c) && !accMap.get(ap.Account__c).Plan__r.isEmpty()){
                ap.addError('Only one plan is permitted per Record type');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your query is correct, the issue here is that `acct.Plan__r` isn't a single SObject instance.

Parent-child subqueries always return an embedded `List<SObject>` in the parent object, even if there is only one (or even zero) child records.

When you're working with a small number of child records, directly accessing the embedded list of child records can work, but the safe method to do access the child records is to use a nested loop.

Aside from that, I'd think that using a `Map<Id, Set<Id>>` would be a better choice for determining if there's already a record for a given account id - plan record type id pair. Using a `Map<Id, String>` limits you to storing a single record type id per account.

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> acctIdToUsedRecTypeIds = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
for(Account acc : accMap.values()){
    // General map population pattern:
    // If we don't have the key in the map, put into the map so we can use it later
    //   in the loop without additional checks
    if(!acctIdToUsedRecTypeIds.containsKey(acc.Id)){
        acctIdToUsedRecTypeIds.put(acc.Id, new Set<Id>());
    }

    // Safest option is to use a nested loop to access child records
    for(Plan__c acctPlan :acc.Plan__r){
        acctIdToUsedRecTypeIds.get(acc.Id).add(accPlan.RecordTypeId);
    }
}
```

Your check a little later on would then be `acctIdToUsedRecTypeIds.get(ap.Account__c).contains(ap.RecordTypeId);`

Comment: Thanks so much!